Why are the site icons offset again?
The site icons (in the "Communities" tab, and in the "Hot Network Questions" sidebar) are misaligned. I've checked on multiple devices and multiple sites, so I don't think this is just on my end. It looks like this:

This has happened before and has been fixed each time, as can be seen:

In 2016
In 2015

There are many other instances of this issue, which seems to be recurring. Please try to fix this.

Look fine to me, FF mobile 126.0.1 and Chrome 125.0.6422.146.

Unable to reproduce. (The most common reason for this is when a new site gets created, but that hasn't happened now.)

Could it be specific to the devices I used? Both devices I tested the problem on were Chromebooks.

Welcome to Meta SE. The icons look fine to me using Edge 125.0.2535.79 on 64-bit Windows 10. FYI, in addition to what Sonic's comment indicates about a new site causing this, there are also other possible reasons, e.g., such as asked & commented about in Site icons all cut off/incorrectly cropped in Hot Network Questions list (in particular there, using 90% zoom).
